# The pattern with functions like `bool`, `either`, etc

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, gadt

I recently learned about [`GADTs`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) and their notation:

E.g.

```
data Maybe a where
  Nothing :: Maybe a
  Just    :: a -> Maybe a

data Either a b where
  Left  :: a -> Either a b
  Right :: b -> Either a b

data Bool where
  False :: Bool
  True  :: Bool
```

Now I noticed a similiarity to functions like [`bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:bool), and [`either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:either), which is basically just like the `GADT` definition:

1. taking every line as an argument
2. replacing the actual type with the next letter of the alphabet
3. and finally returning a function `Type -> (the letter of step 2)`

E.g.

```
maybe  :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
bool   :: a -> a -> Bool -> a
```

This also includes `foldr`, but I noticed that e.g. Tuple doesn't have such a function, though you could easily define it:

```
tuple :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c
tuple f (x,y) = f x y
```

What is this pattern? It seems to me these functions alleviate the need for pattern matching (because they give a general way for each case) and thus *every* function operating on the type can be defined in terms of this function.

Comment: You mean [uncurry](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry)?

Comment: I don't see the relation between my concept and currying

Comment: "*Functions like `bool`*"?

Comment: `bool` is a function in Haskell defined in `Data.Bool`

Comment: @hgiesel: ah, thanks for the reference :) This actually looks like a *catamorphism* to me :)

Comment: I feel more like a catamorphism is a specialized version of what I describe, because a catamorphism works of a function that is `(f a -> a)`, while this is `(f a -> b)`

Comment: I think @bheklilr is saying that your `tuple` function is identical to `uncurry`.

Comment: Ok, I see, yes, he is right.

Comment: This is indeed a catamorphism, albeit you are using a different choice of type variables. A general cata has type `(F a -> a) -> T -> a` where `T=Fix F`. Above, `T=Maybe b= 1+b` and `F a -> a` becomes `(1+b)->a` which is isomorphic to `(a , b->a)` so the cata becomes `(a, b->a) -> Maybe b -> a` which is your `maybe`, except for renamed tyvars and isos/currying.

Comment: @chi I'm sorry, I don't quite get your answer, could you maybe elaborate it in an answer?

Comment: This is often referred to as _Church Encoding_ but in a typed language it is more properly _Boehm-Berarducci Encoding_.

Comment: @chi could you please clarify about the `T = Maybe b = Fix F = F a` thing?

Comment: @WillNess The `Maybe b` type is not recursive, unlike lists/trees. Hence, it can be seen as a "fixed point" `Fix F` of the _constant_ type function `F a = 1+b`, so that  `T=Fix F=F(Fix F)=1+b` holds trivially, since `F a` does not depend on `a`.

Comment: @hgiesel This is a bit broad. Some discussion can be found in the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/2984/recursion-schemes) but it's still preliminary, and needs more examples, IMHO. I also answered a related question on [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78101/what-are-structural-recursion-primitive-recursion-recursion-combinator-and-rec) yesterday.

Comment: @chi thank you. the "constant type function" did the trick.

Comment: @hgiesel also, on simpler level (and this may be obvious), this can be referred to as "case analysis" functions: `maybe b f v = case v of Nothing -> b; Just a -> f a`. Number of arguments obviously corresponds to the number of cases in the data type definition. Having such functions defined for each datatype obviates the need to have the `case` primitive as part of a language. One could imagine a language without `case` expressions, where datatype definition facilities include defining such functions. With tuples there's only one case, hence case analysis is a no-op: `tuple f (x,y) = f x y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the types you mention are not really GADTs, they are plain ADTs, since the return type of each constructor is always `T a`. A proper GADT would be something like

```
data T a where
   K1 :: T Bool  -- not T a
```

Anyway, the technique you mention is a well known method to encode algebraic data types into (polymorphic) functions. It goes under many names, like Church encoding, Boehm-Berarducci encoding, endcoding as a catamorphism, etc. Sometimes the Yoneda lemma is used to justify this approach, but there's no need to understand the category-theoretic machinery to understand the method.

Basically, the idea is the following. All the ADTs can be generated by

- product types `(,) a b`
- sum types `Either a b`
- arrow types `a -> b`
- unit type `()`
- void type `Void` (rarely used in Haskell, but theoretically nice)
- variables (if the type bing defined has parameters)
- possibly, basic types (`Integer`, ...)
- type level-recursion

Type level recursion is used when some value constructor takes the type which is being defined as an argument. The classic example is Peano-style naturals:

```
data Nat where
   O :: Nat
   S :: Nat -> Nat
     -- ^^^ recursive!
```

Lists are also common:

```
data List a where
   Nil :: List a
   Cons :: a -> List a -> List a
             -- ^^^^^^ recursive!
```

Types like `Maybe a`, pairs, etc. are non recursive.

Note that each ADT, recursive or not, can be reduced to a single constructor with a sigle argument, by summing (`Either`) over all the constructors, and multiplying all the arguments. For instance, `Nat` is isomorphic to

```
data Nat1 where
  O1 :: () -> Nat
  S1 :: Nat -> Nat
```

which is isomorphic to

```
data Nat2 where K2 :: (Either () Nat) -> Nat
```

Lists become

```
data List1 a where K1 :: (Either () (a, List a)) -> List a
```

The steps above make use of the algebra of types, which makes the sum and products of types obey the same rules as high school algebra, while `a -> b` behaves like the exponential `b^a`.

Hence, we can write any ADT in the form

```
-- pseudo code
data T where
   K :: F T -> T
type F k = .....
```

For instance

```
type F_Nat k = Either () k      -- for T = Nat
type F_List_a k = Either () (a, k) -- for T = List a
```

(Note that the latter type function `F` depends on `a`, but it's not important right now.)

Non recursive types will not use `k`:

```
type F_Maybe_a k = Either () a     -- for T = Maybe a
```

Note that constructor `K` above makes the type `T` isomorphic to `F T` (let's ignore the lifting / extra bottom introduced by it). Essentially, we have that

```
Nat ~= F Nat = Either () Nat
List a ~= F (List a) = Either () (a, List a)
Maybe a ~= F (Maybe a) = Either () a
```

We can even formalize this further by abstracting from `F`

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
```

By definition `Fix F` will now be isomorphic to `F (Fix F)`. We could let

```
type Nat = Fix F_Nat
```

(In Haskell, we need a newtype wrapper around `F_Nat`, which I omit for clarity.)

Finally, the general encoding, or catamorphism, is:

```
cata :: (F k -> k) -> Fix F -> k
```

This assumes that `F` is a functor.

For `Nat`, we get

```
cata :: (Either () k -> k) -> Nat -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: (() -> k, k -> k) -> Nat -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: (k, k -> k) -> Nat -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: k -> (k -> k) -> Nat -> k
```

Note the "high school albegra" steps, where `k^(1+k) = k^1 * k^k`, hence `Either () k -> k ~= (() -> k, k -> k)`.

Note that we get two arguments, `k` and `k->k` which correspond to `O` and `S`. This is not a coincidence -- we summed over all the constructors. This means that `cata` expects to be passed the value of type `k` which "plays the role of `O`" there, and then the value of type `k -> k` which plays the role of `S`.

More informally, `cata` is telling us that, if we want to map a natural in `k`, we only have to state what is the "zero" inside `k` and how to take the "successor" in `k`, and then every `Nat` can be mapped consequently.

For lists we get:

```
cata :: (Either () (a, k) -> k) -> List a -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: (() -> k, (a, k) -> k) -> List a -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: (k, a -> k -> k) -> List a -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: k -> (a -> k -> k) -> List a -> k
```

which is `foldr`.

Again, this is `cata` telling us that, if we state how to take the "empty list" in `k` and to "cons" `a` and `k` inside `k`, we can map any list in `k`.

`Maybe a` is the same:

```
cata :: (Either () a -> k) -> Maybe a -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: (() -> k, a -> k) -> Maybe a -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: (k, a -> k) -> Maybe a -> k
-- isomorphic to
cata :: k -> (a -> k) -> Maybe a -> k
```

If we can map `Nothing` in `k`, and perform `Just` mapping `a` in `k`, the we can map any `Maybe a` in `k`.

If we try to apply the same approach to `Bool` and `(a,b)` we reach the functions which were posted in the questions.

More advanced theoretical topics to look up:

- (initial) F-algebras in category theory
- eliminators / recursors / induction principles in type theory (these can be applied to GADTs as well)